# Get total mins for today

Tags: powershell, iis

I am looking for total mins for today,

Tried this way but not working.

```
$from_date = Get-Date
$Start_date = $from_date.ToShortDateString()

($from_date - $Start_date).Minute
```

Comment: Do you mean the total number of minutes that have passed since midnight?

Comment: Yes, Total number of mins from midnight to as of now

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it this way:

```
PS C:\> (Get-Date).TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes
651.356536988333
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `ToShortDateString()` if you want to do further arithmetic cprocessing on the object, it'll turn it into a string.

Substract the `Date` property from the object and grab the `TotalMinutes` property value from the resulting timespan:

```
$from_date = Get-Date
$MinutesSinceMidnight = ($from_date - $from_date.Date).TotalMinutes
```

The result will be in decimal form. Use [`Math.Floor()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb(v=vs.110).aspx) if you need an integer value:

```
[System.Math]::Floor($MinutesSinceMidnight)
```